# Object "undefined" in Mocha script. Not sure how to pass on value

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am running a mocha test on a bunch of endpoints and I'm not able to pass on results to the next test case
Failing at line    `var result = data["results"];`
`error:data undefined`

````
    it('should get series', async () => {
        let data = await legacy.getCategories(config[process.env.TEST_ENV].url, config[process.env.TEST_ENV].origin);
        console.log(data);
        expect(data).to.be.an('array').that.is.not.empty;
        done();
    });

    var unallowedGuids = config[process.env.TEST_ENV].unallowedGuids;
    var result = data["results"];

    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
        let guid = result[i]["guid"];
        let showName = result[i]["title"];
        if (!unallowedGuids.includes(guid)){
                it('should get colletions guid', async () => {
                let data = await legacy.collectionsGuid(config[process.env.TEST_ENV].url, config[process.env.TEST_ENV].origin, guid);
                expect(data).to.be.an('array').that.is.not.empty;
                done();
    });
                it('should get series guid', async () => {
                let data = await legacy.seriesGuid(config[process.env.TEST_ENV].url, config[process.env.TEST_ENV].origin, guid);
                expect(data).to.be.an('array').that.is.not.empty;
                done();
    });
        } 
        else
            console.log("excluded", guid);
    }

});```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is related to variable scope.

Try modifying your code like so:

```
    let data; // initialize "data" outside of the "it" callback function

    it('should get series', async () => {
      data = await legacy.getCategories(config[process.env.TEST_ENV].url, config[process.env.TEST_ENV].origin);
      console.log(data);
      expect(data).to.be.an('array').that.is.not.empty;
      done();
    });

    var unallowedGuids = config[process.env.TEST_ENV].unallowedGuids;
    var result = data["results"]; // data will be defined here
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @steamDev. data only defined inside of it() .. as soon as I try to utilized it like the script you modified I receive ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
```

Comment: It may be because `it` hasn't executed by the time `results` is being declared. You might need set the value of `data` in a `before` hook method. Use this article for reference https://zaiste.net/modern_node_js_async_await_based_testing_with_mocha_chai/

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you got undefined because `var result = data["results"];` is executed first before your `it('should get series', ..)` function.

One solution is to restructure the test to make sure the order of execution is correct. We can use `before()` or `beforeEach()` For example:

```
let data;

before(async () => {
  data = await legacy.getCategories(config[process.env.TEST_ENV].url, config[process.env.TEST_ENV].origin);                
});

it('get collection and series guid', async function() {
  var unallowedGuids = config[process.env.TEST_ENV].unallowedGuids;
  var result = data["results"]; // it will be executed after data is fetched in `before()`

  for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
      let guid = result[i]["guid"];
      let showName = result[i]["title"];
      if (!unallowedGuids.includes(guid)){
        let data = await legacy.collectionsGuid(config[process.env.TEST_ENV].url, config[process.env.TEST_ENV].origin, guid);
        expect(data).to.be.an('array').that.is.not.empty;

        let data = await legacy.seriesGuid(config[process.env.TEST_ENV].url, config[process.env.TEST_ENV].origin, guid);
        expect(data).to.be.an('array').that.is.not.empty;
      } 
      else {
        console.log("excluded", guid);
      }
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you also can put the data fetching in same `it()` function

```
// no before()

it('get collection and series guid', async function() {
  var unallowedGuids = config[process.env.TEST_ENV].unallowedGuids;

  var data = await legacy.getCategories(config[process.env.TEST_ENV].url, config[process.env.TEST_ENV].origin);
  var result = data["results"];

  ....
});
```

Hope it helps